# Best way to test JPA with H2 database?

Tags: spring, jpa, junit4, h2

I need to test JPA with H2 database using spring and Junit, i found on the net many way but i'm not sure about the best one.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why do people always think there is one "best" way? Why not try things and see what works best for you, in terms of your code and situation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a test profile for your Spring application and create H2 Data source in that profile and inject the same. If yours is a spring boot project then the data source can be profiled using property files like application-dev.properties or application-test.properties. Else create the different bean definitions under different profiles. By default Maven/Gradle runs test with profile=test.

Hence when running test, the H2 Database is picked up. H2 in memory database would be even better, since every time test starts it can drop/create.

Comment here if u are looking for any particular specification/measure to decide the good approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed couple of approaches for configuring Spring/JPA test suite and it is kind of hard to pinpoint the best one. As long as they cover the points mentioned below you are free to use any of them, just try them out and see which one suites you the best.

- Make sure that configuration managing the JPA database configuration is externalized. You can achieve this by specifying a different spring profile or overriding the Spring PropertyConfigurer. For the Spring boot project the base class for your tests could be similar to the code snippet below :

```
    @ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, locations = "classpath:applicationContext-integrationtest.xml")
    @ActiveProfiles("integrationtest")
    @Ignore("An abstract base class for the tests")
    public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    }
```

- Make sure that the properties controlling datasource configuration are overridden in the integration test properties file. The main DB specific properties are :

  - Database username (usually set on datasource/connection pool) - `sa`
  - Database password (usually set on datasource/connection pool) - ``
  - Database connection URL (usually set on datasource/connection pool) - `jdbc:h2:database/integrationtest`
  - Database JDBC driver class (usually set on datasource/connection pool) - `org.h2.Driver`
  - Database Dialect (usually set on the EntityManagerFactory JPA provider specific configuration) - `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library. I works amazingly well and with very less fuss.
https://github.com/mmnaseri/spring-data-mock